# The selector "my-app-test" did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to user angular2 in my application. The problem is that I concatenate all the components code for angular in one big file that I will import in the index.html page (so it will be present in all the pages).

But I always get `The selector "my-app-test" did not match any elements`because obviously in the index.html there is no `<my-app-text/>` tag. In angular 1 I could declare a directive and then these directive got instantiated only when its was on the current page.

How I can archive the same thing in angular2 so that angular didn't try to find the correct selector but in contrary instantiate the component only when it found in the page?

Thanks

For now I have the following code:

```
(function() {
    var AppComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'my-app-test',
            template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
        })
            .Class({
                constructor: function() {}
            });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases usually incorrectly ended file is an issue. Make sure you remove all comments (if you compress the file to one line) and you not have any syntax errors in any of your JS files. A common practice is to add few semicolons between files being combined just in case some of them have errors.

However, I'd start with running JSLint on your sources a get those possible errors detected and removed first.